# Avoid page scrolling on a div - AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, scroll

In my website, I want to integrate an animation 3D (already done) which also has a zoom option.

When you are on the image (mouseover) and you scroll it actually zoom but it is also scroll the entire page.

This animation is integrated the following way :

```
 <iframe id="myanimation" src="http://myanimation..." scrolling="no" content="user-scalable=no;"></iframe>
```

A lot of solutions have been given in javascript or jQuery but I would like an AngularJS way to do that.

I have already thought about wrapping this iframe in a div which should have avoided scrolling the entire page:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="$window.body.scrolling='no';" ng-mouseleave="$window.body.scrolling='yes';">
```

or with the CSS property overflow :

```
<div ng-mouseenter="$windiw.body.style.overflow='hidden';" ng-mouseleave="$windiw.body.style.overflow='auto';">
```

Is there a way of doing it with CSS or should I think about writing code to avoid this behaviour?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What's wrong with the regular $event.stopPropagation?

Comment: You mean like this : 
    <div ng-mouseenter="$event.stopPropagation">?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: I usually do it in the controller/directive when I bind the mousewheel event to the element, then I do it. Don't believe it works straight like that.